# App is stopping while adding lifecycle extension library

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

So I am learning LiveData in Android. Then I added the dependency

```
api 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
```

and when I run it the apps stops

I checked the code by commenting all the parts of ViewModelClass and removed its initialization from MainActivity

But in logcat it shows some kind of weird error

Logcat -

```
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 D   AndroidRuntime                               Shutting down VM
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.dasher.testground, PID: 31681
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/arch/core/internal/FastSafeIterableMap;
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.<init>(LifecycleRegistry.java:59)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.<init>(SupportActivity.java:47)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:28)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:34)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:67)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.dasher.testground.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1096)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dasher.testground-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.dasher.testground-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 19 more
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 20 more
02-10 17:48:53.361 31681 31681 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Thanks
Any answers will be appreciated

****Note:****
**I dont have a PC or lap so I am using AIDE found in playstore**

Comment: `If you want I will provide the logcat` always, we can't guess what's wrong, logcat is the only way to _know_ what is wrong

Comment: Ok I will give it

Comment: I have added rhe logcat